# Configure script for ffmpeg does not find sdl2

Tags: ffmpeg

Environment:

```
 Ubuntu 16.04
 ffmpeg source code version 3.4.2
```

SDL2 installed

```
$ pkg-config --exists --print-errors sdl2
$ sdl2-config --cflags
-I/usr/include/SDL2 -D_REENTRANT
$ sdl2-config --libs
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSDL2
$ sdl2-config --version
2.0.4
```

Here is part of my configuration shell script:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$TARGET_DIR/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
--prefix="$TARGET_DIR" \
--pkg-config-flags="--static" \
--enable-sdl2 \
```

When I run the script, the error I get is "sdl2 requested but not found."

What is it that I am missing? Regards.

Comment: Check the end of config.log in ffbuild/

Answer (score 2):

Turns out a configure flag was causing this problem.

My script was based on https://github.com/zimbatm/ffmpeg-static/blob/master/build.sh.

Removing the following flag fixed the problem:

```
--extra-ldexeflags="-static" \
```